# "Clone in Mac' fails on GitHub. Takes me to download page every time

Tags: macos, git, osx-mountain-lion, github-for-mac

I've reinstalled, uninstalled, restarted but "Clone in Mac' on any repository page fails and takes me to the GitHub download page every time.

It was working fine earlier this week but today won't do anything useful.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It appears not only do you have to log in to the website, you have to log in to the application once as well so it knows you've got it installed. Then refresh the git repo page and the links will automagically change from the download page to an open-application page.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I logged out, then back in to GitHub, and I have the application open on my desktop too (there's no option to log in/out of that), yet I still get sent to the download page when using the "Clone to Desktop" button from the web page.

Comment: I had to log out of GitHub for Mac, and then back into it, before it started working

Comment: Also, make sure you are logged into the same account on both GitHub site and GitHub for Mac.

Answer (score 12):

I tried the above suggestions of making sure I was logged in to both the site and the Github-Mac application (which I already was) and installing the CLI tools. This didn't fix it for me. After some digging I found [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/github-conduit) which explains how it works.

There should be a server listening on your localhost with https://ghconduit.com:25035/status and it should return a json string that looks something like this:

```
{"capabilities":["status","unique_id","url-parameter-filepath"],"running":true,"server_version":"5"}
```

In my case I did not get a result so I tried 127.0.0.1 instead of ghconduit.com and that fixed it.

TL;DR: Add an entry for **`127.0.0.1       ghconduit.com`** to your /etc/hosts file and refresh the github page you are on and the clone on desktop function will work.

Comment: Going to: https://127.0.0.1:25035/status returns nothing for me. Any tips for troubleshooting that?

Answer (score 8):

As was noted in the comments: You **must be logged in** to Github for the "Clone on Mac" button work.

*(This answer serves mostly to remove this question from the "unanswered" list, since the asker does not seem to be closing it)*

Answer (score 5):

Even doing all the above failed for me, but here's what did work:

Open a new tab.

Paste this in the address bar (without quotes):
"github-mac://openRepo/"

On the repo you want to clone, copy the HTTPS clone URL, and paste it after the link above. Press enter.

If the server is listening on your Mac @rjason-lindberg mentioned, then it should open up in GutHub for Mac.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem, and I found two steps necessary to get it working: the "log in" answer above, and to open GitHub.app, got to Preferences > Advanced > Install Command Line Tools.
This took no time. I then refreshed the github page, and saw that the link now led to something like: "github-mac://openRepo/https://github.com/......"
Click it and it worked.

Comment: Almost worked for me. The URL generated by clicking on "Open in Desktop" on the web site is `x-github-client://openRepo/https://blahblah`. I discover that by holding down splat key while clicking on "Open in Desktop," opening the URL in a new Tab. If i manually change the URL in Chrome's type-in address box on that new tab to `github-mac://openRepo/https://blahblah` then the desktop app opens. I don't know how to hook up `x-github-client` with `github-mac`, so I'm still blocked, but there is a clue.

Answer (score 3):

I have answered my own question: the trick is TO BE LOGGED IN on the GitHub website.  As stated by Neil above, you need to be logged into the application too.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me.  I tried logging out (both GitHub and GitHub for Mac), revoking the application access key, quitting the application, reinstalling the GitHub command-line tools (via the Preferences pane), etc.

What did work for me:

1. **Clone (Edit: I think I might have meant "Fork"?*) the repository on github.com**.  (Yes, through the web interface)
2. In the GitHub for Mac application, access File > New Repository... and choose "Clone".  Select the repo you just created on github.com and clone on, my friend!  Clone on.

*It has been a while since I wrote this answer, so I'm not sure if I actually did mean "Clone"... I understand that forking and cloning are certainly not the same thing.  I'll leave this answer here in case it happens to inspire a thought for someone!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it seemed to work.

- Go to Keychain Access and delete all stored passwords (Internet,
  application, Web form) with reference to GitHub.
- Login in fresh on to the site as well as from the Mac OS desktop application
- Store the passwords this time

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers did the trick for me. But seeing that neither https://ghconduit.com:25035/status nor https://localhost:25035/status was able to connect I realized that the Conduit process wasn't running. It's in "GitHub.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/GitHub Conduit"
open that, and clone to desktop finally works again.
Don't know why GitHub.app didn't start it by itself, but at least it works now.

edit: After each reboot the GitHub Conduit process needs to be manually started again.